Why am I getting a 403 error when trying to play YouTube videos using youtube_explode_dart in Flutter?
I am using the youtube_explode_dart package to play YouTube videos in my Flutter app, but recently, I started getting the following error when trying to stream videos:
Unhandled Exception: YoutubeExplodeException: Video returned 403 (stream: 18)

The 403 Forbidden error in youtube_explode_dart happens when the package cannot access YouTube video streams due to changes in YouTube’s backend or outdated stream formats. This issue became common for many users when the older versions of youtube_explode_dart were no longer compatible with YouTube’s updated stream structure.
Solution:
The error you're encountering can be resolved by updating the youtube_explode_dart package to the latest version.
Recently, the youtube_explode_dart package released version 2.2.2 (released a week ago) that addresses these issues and restores compatibility with YouTube's latest API changes.
To fix the issue, you need to upgrade the package in your Flutter project to version 2.2.2 or later.
Steps to Upgrade:
1. Update pubspec.yaml: Open your pubspec.yaml file and update the youtube_explode_dart dependency to the latest version:
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
youtube_explode_dart: ^2.2.2
2. Run flutter pub get: After updating the version, fetch the new dependency by running:
flutter pub get
3. Test Your Application: Run your application again and the 403 error should be resolved.
Why This Happens:
YouTube frequently updates its backend, which can break functionality in packages like youtube_explode_dart that rely on accessing video streams. The package maintainers released version 2.2.2 to handle these changes and ensure compatibility with YouTube’s current API.
By upgrading to this version, your Flutter app will be able to stream YouTube videos again without encountering the 403 error.

Still doesn't work. Even 2.2.3 doesn't work.

Hello @Ataberk,  That solution worked for me in my case; however, your case might be different.

does it still work??

Yes, that's why I posted it!!

Posting date is Oct 3. I asked 1 week later. YouTube is patching their systems. That is why I asked.
